# How to acces jquery object data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have an output from an ajax response call

You can view the image here: [image]

This is the output from: `console.log(data)` but I don't know how to access these values? Any help?

Comment: Use data.each(function(){console.log(this.dataset)})

Comment: I don't think that is a jQuery object (note the [brackets]).  I think it is a JavaScript array that contains JavaScript objects.

Comment: Did you try 'data[3]. Dataset' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dataset` is the HTML5 way to store *Node related* data. Its pretty much a property that is available on any node and get get accessed like

```
MyjQueryCollection[ 3 ].dataset.lastId;
```

You need to grab the underlaying *DOM node*, you cannot access that property on a jQuery object/collection directly, since it does not get abstracted by jQuery. This is accomplished by referencing the indexed value of the node here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$obj.data('lastId')
```